# django 1.8 how to retrieve image file path from the database when using upload_to

Tags: django

I have an image file in my django model. I'm trying to retrieve the path of the image while I've forced the output directory using **upload_to** but it is not returning the correct path.

```
def signatures_path(instance, filename):
    return 'signatures/{}/{}'\
        .format(instance.id, filename)


class Designation(models.Model):
    designation = models.TextField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    signature = models.ImageField(upload_to=signatures_path,\
        blank=True, null=True, default=None, validators=[validate_png])


Designation.objects.filter(user__username=username).values_list('signature', flat=True)
[u'sig'jpg']


x = Designation.objects.get(user__username=username)
print x.signature.path
/home/me/myapp/myapp/media/sig.jpg
```

but I expect it to be:
/home/me/myapp/myapp/media/signature/None/sig.jpg

How to retrieve the correct path?
Note that there is a "**None**" directory in the path which does not seem to be stored anywhere.

---

update:
The problem was because of the way I was saving the file.
I was saving it with:

```
Designation.objects.filter(user__username=username).update(signature=signature)
```

When I changed it to:

```
x=Designation.objects.get(user__username=username)
x.signature=signature
x.save()
```

then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `print x.signature.url` instead of `print x.signature.path`. It returns the absolute path of file.

Comment: uh, I thought I tried url but apparently not. Thanks

Comment: It does not work from some objects. I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: It's strange. It works when I save the image in the admin page, but does not work when I write a query to save the image so there must be something wrong with the way I'm saving the image.

Comment: Do you know how to save the image programatically to make it display the url correctly?

Comment: Files uploaded by user or collected using "python manage collectstatic" would be stored in path defined by MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT respectively. You have to use <img src={{ signature.url }}> in your template.